# How to plot the 2-D graph of $|x|+|x+y|=1$?

Tags: plotting, visualization

#### Problem Description:

Today，I am countered with a integral problem that I need visualize a 2D graph of the equation $|x|+|x+y|=1$

I plots it step-by-step by hand:

- When $x \geq 0,   x+|x+y|=1$
  $$\begin{cases}
          2x+y=1 & y\geq -x \\
          y=-1   & y<-x
  \end{cases}
  $$
- When $x<0,   -x+|x+y|=1$

$$\begin{cases}
        y=1 &  y \geq -x \\
        2x+y=-1   & y<-x
\end{cases}
$$

So I ploted this graph by four lines.

[image: the 2-D graph of Abs[x]+Abs[x+y]==1?]

However,now I want to use *Mathematica* to solve it.

Have a try:

```
Plot[y /. {Solve[Abs@x + Abs@(x + y) == 1, y]}, {x, -1, 1}, 
AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

but the *Mathematica* give the following warning information:

> “Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>”

So I think my solution has flaws.My **question** is how to revise it or give another method to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No warning information:

```
With[{sol = y /. Solve[Abs@x + Abs@(x + y) == 1, y, Reals]},
 Plot[sol, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> 2, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
 ]

Plot[y /. Solve[Abs@x + Abs@(x + y) == 1, y, Reals] //  Evaluate,
 {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> 2, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

Answer (score 13):

```
ContourPlot[Abs[x] + Abs[x + y] == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]